# Undefined symbol in custom costmap layer during runtime caused by tf2 Buffer transform

Tags: navigation, costmap, tf2, plugin, 2dcostmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am writing a custom costmap layer to read data from a radar sensor and turn it into a costmap, and I'm facing some issues running it. I get the following error when it runs:

```
symbol lookup error: /home/mkhoory/sdc/catkin_ws/devel/lib//libRadarDataLayer.so: undefined symbol: _ZN3tf212getTimestampIN13geometry_msgs15PolygonStamped_ISaIvEEEEERKN3ros4TimeERKT_
```

What the related code is trying to do is create a PolygonStamped from the radar data and convert it to world coordinates via tf2.

```
tfBuffer.transform(polyRadar, polyWorld, globalFrame);
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. The code compiles fine, and it's only when the plugin reaches the above line that it tells me that it's an undefined reference. I tried including tf2_geometry_msgs.h but that didn't do anything. What am I missing?

EDIT: Here's my CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(my_project_processing)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  rospy
  std_msgs
  geometry_msgs
  message_generation
  tf
  tf2
  tf2_geometry_msgs
  costmap_2d
  dynamic_reconfigure
  my_project_sensors
)

find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS system thread)

add_message_files(
    FILES
    CommandMessage.msg
)

generate_messages(
  DEPENDENCIES
  std_msgs
  geometry_msgs
)

catkin_package(
  INCLUDE_DIRS include
  LIBRARIES
  CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp rospy std_msgs tf message_runtime geometry_msgs message_generation
  DEPENDS Boost
)

# let's use C++11
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++11 ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}")

include_directories(
  include
  ${tf2_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

# Costmap2D Layer plugin
add_library(RadarDataLayer lib/RadarDataLayer.cpp)
target_link_libraries(RadarDataLayer ${Boost_LIBRARIES} ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/267803/undefined-symbol-in-custom-costmap-layer-during-runtime-caused-by-tf2-buffer-transform/) by [9a3eedi](https://answers.ros.org/users/27142/9a3eedi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2017-08-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-08-01**:
This is a (deferred) linker error, not a compilation issue.

Please post your `CMakeLists.txt` -- make sure to remove all the boilerplate comments from it first (lines starting with `#`).

**Comment by [9a3eedi](https://answers.ros.org/users/27142/9a3eedi/) on 2017-08-01**:
I think I may have found the problem. tf2_geometry_msgs only supports native transformations certain types of messages from geometry_msgs, and PolygonStamped isn't one of them, according to this link http://wiki.ros.org/tf2_geometry_msgs . I'm not sure yet so I'm going to try another type first.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-08-01**:
I would expect to see a compiler error ("no candidates" or "no matching function call for ..") in that case, not a linker error. A 'missing symbol error' basically means that the compiler embedded the use of an external symbol in your library, but you didn't link against all needed dependencies.

**Comment by [9a3eedi](https://answers.ros.org/users/27142/9a3eedi/) on 2017-08-01**:
Hi, I added my CMakeLists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It turns out that tf2_geometry_msgs does not support transforming PolygonStamped!

I changed my code so that instead of transforming PolygonStamped, it would transform each individual Point in it (i.e. I was transforming PointStamped instead now). This seems to work fine and did not get any issues.

---

Originally posted by [9a3eedi](https://answers.ros.org/users/27142/9a3eedi/) with karma: 63 on 2017-08-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-08-09**:
Ok. Thanks for reporting back.

Would it make sense to add the support and submit a pull request against `tf2_geometry_msgs` to get it merged upstream?

**Comment by [9a3eedi](https://answers.ros.org/users/27142/9a3eedi/) on 2017-08-10**:
I think it would make sense for convenience sake. I can imagine a lot of reasons why you'd want to do it.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-08-10**:
Seeing as you've already done it, would it be possible for you submit a PR? :)